# Dynamic text-pattern detection algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, text, nlp, machine-learning, data-modeling

I was wondering if such algorithm exists. I have a bunch of text documents and would like to find a pattern among all these documents, if a pattern exists. Please note im NOT trying to classify the documents all i want to do is find a pattern if it exists among some documents. Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific what kind of pattern you want to detect.

Comment: pattern of the text(meaning) structure

Comment: I don't understand how such a vague question could get two upvotes. There are zillions of possible patterns and structures to be found in text. I'm voting to close; please rethink your problem.

Comment: Are you talking about [Latent Semantic Indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing)? Or something like it?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Are you trying to detect a heiracrchical structure, discover clusters, determine relationships based on the content, ? To take it to another level are you trying to stack multiple approaches? What is your end-result?

Comment: @Larsmans I don't think a close is appropriate. He's asked a generic question, but I'm not sure may be considering the approaches to his problem

Comment: @monksy: the OP doesn't describe a well-defined *problem*, that's my reason for closing. There is no correct answer to this question, unless it's a book-sized tract on NLP.

Comment: @monksy I have 100s of documents and i would like to find relationships or patterns between these documents based on the content(i.e meaning or logical flow). After the algorithm finds a pattern, i would like to use this pattern and try to classify new documents and check if they have that particular pattern in them or not. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeG Why don't you edit your question and add in a couple of mock input/output descriptions of the algorithm you are searching for that will help us understand what you are want..

Comment: To me it sounds like 2 different pathways:
1. You're trying to extract templates
2. You're trying to create clusters [hierarchical or flat]
Which is it?  [Please update your question with that]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question as it stands now is kinda vague.. you kinda need to know what you are looking for in order to be able to find it.
Some ideas that may be of use -

1. Get n-gram counts for each document separately for n = 1,2,3,4 and then compare the frequencies of each ngram across the documents. This should help you find commonly occuring phrases across all documents.
2. Get a part of speech tagger to get convert all the docs into a stream of POS tags and then do the same as 1
3. Use a PCFG software such as the Stanford Parser to get parse trees for all the sentences across all the documents, and then try to figure out how similar the distribution of sentence structures are for different documents.

Comment: well what you mentioned "calculates" the polarity of the documents. What i would like to FIND is a pattern(meaning or logical flow) that exists between these documents. Thanks! @adi92

Comment: Sorry, thats still too vague.. please give me some specific examples of what types of input do you want your algorithm to take, and what type of outputs do you want it to give out.. A big part of solving a problem is being able to precisely define it

Comment: By normalizing the ngram counts on a per-doc basis, one can make a multinomial distribution which gives higher probability to words and phrases that occur frequently in this doc. then by comparing the distributions for different docs (euclidean distance), one can guess which docs are more similar to each other than they are to the other ones.. docs which are more similar are more likely to have similar meanings or logical flows?